# OO Design for using libGDX's HttpResponseListener

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, libgdx, runnable

I have lots of different http calls to make, and have been constructing custom listeners for each one.  The listeners are all the same, except for a method call or two within the handleHttpResponse. So most of the following gets rewritten each and every time:

```
 HttpResponseListener listener = new HttpResponseListener() {
         String status;
            public void handleHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                getSession(httpResponse);
                String result = httpResponse.getResultAsString();
                if (result != null) {
                    getNeeds(result);   //  <== unique part
                }
                System.out.println("Network Response:: Success");
            }
     
            public void failed(Throwable t) {
                    status = "fail";
                    System.out.println("Network Response:: [Fail] " + status);
                    t.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {
                status = "cancelled";
                System.out.println("[getNeedType()] Network Response:: [Cancelled] " + status);
            }
     };
```

How do I de-clutter my code from all these repetitive re-pastes?  Within the javadoc it says to:

> Passing data to the        * rendering thread should be done using {@link
> Application#postRunnable(java.lang.Runnable runnable)}

Haven't used runnables before, but I think they're custom blocks of logic to be executed.  Despite the 'post' prefix I can't see how to attach a runnable to the end of the listeners execution.  I'm thinking to extend the HttpResponseListener to accept a Runnable as an argument, then call the Runnable block at the point in handleHttpResponse when I get my results back.  But how do I pass the results string to the runnable?  Runnables don't see to take any arguments.  Do you extend the runnable as well to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a new abstract class implementing `HttpResponseListener`. Implement cancelled, handleHttpResponse and failed methods the way you use, add the abstract method `getNeeds` to your class.

From now on, use your new abstract class.